# Combining indicator parameters causing - TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Tags: python, pandas, class, exception, algorithmic-trading

Trying to combine RSI indicator parameters with my already working EMA indicator parameters causing an error. After research I am still struggling. Any help is extremely grateful, can provide full code if needed

```
def calculations(df):
    in_long = False
    in_short = False

    #EMA's:
    df['short_ema'] = pd.DataFrame.ewm(df['close'], span = short_span).mean()
    df['long_ema'] = pd.DataFrame.ewm(df['close'], span = long_span).mean()
    
    #RSI:
    df['RSI'] = pd.DataFrame(talib.RSI(df['close'], rsi_period))

    #IN TRADE?
    df['in_uptrend'] = 'N/A'
    for current in range(1, len(df.index)):
        previous = current - 1
        #LONG POSITION
        if df['RSI'] > rsi_mid:
            if df['short_ema'][current] > df['long_ema'][current] and df['close'][current] > df['short_ema'][current] and in_long == False:
                df['in_uptrend'][current] = 'OPEN LONG'
                in_long = True
                
            elif df['close'][current] > df['long_ema'][current] and in_long == True:
                df['in_uptrend'][current] = 'Still in long'
            
            elif df['close'][current] < df['long_ema'][current] and in_long == True: 
                df['in_uptrend'][current] = 'Close long'
                in_long = False

        #SHORT POSITION
        if df['RSI'] < rsi_mid:
            if df['short_ema'][current] < df['long_ema'][current] and df['close'][current] < df['short_ema'][current] and in_short == False:
                df['in_uptrend'][current] = 'OPEN SHORT'
                in_short = True
                
            elif df['close'][current] < df['long_ema'][current] and in_short == True:
                df['in_uptrend'][current] = 'Still in short'
            
            elif df['close'][current] > df['long_ema'][current] and in_short == True:
                df['in_uptrend'][current] = 'Close short'
                in_short = False


    emas = df[['short_ema', 'long_ema']].max(axis=1)
    return df
```

Here is the entire error message with the Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/hamishmcpherson/Desktop/EMA Bot/app.py", line 95, in 
> run_schedule()   File "/Users/hamishmcpherson/Desktop/EMA Bot/app.py", line 86, in run_schedule
> schedule.run_pending()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/**init**.py",
> line 780, in run_pending
> default_scheduler.run_pending()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/**init**.py",
> line 100, in run_pending
> self._run_job(job)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/**init**.py",
> line 172, in _run_job
> ret = job.run()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/schedule/**init**.py",
> line 661, in run
> ret = self.job_func()   File "/Users/hamishmcpherson/Desktop/EMA Bot/app.py", line 78, in run_bot
> calculation = calculations(df)   File "/Users/hamishmcpherson/Desktop/EMA Bot/app.py", line 43, in
> calculations
> if df['RSI'] > rsi_mid:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py",
> line 65, in new_method
> return method(self, other)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py",
> line 45, in **gt**
> return self._cmp_method(other, operator.gt)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py",
> line 4978, in _cmp_method
> res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py",
> line 240, in comparison_op
> return invalid_comparison(lvalues, rvalues, op)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/invalid.py",
> line 34, in invalid_comparison
> raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}") TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and
> str Exception ignored in: <function Exchange.**del** at
> 0x7f8398c35f70> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py",
> line 397, in **del**   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 747, in close   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 325, in close   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py",
> line 222, in clear   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/_collections.py",
> line 100, in clear   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py",
> line 173, in    File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 494, in close TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit
> from BaseException is not allowed

Comment: What is the exact traceback of the error?

Comment: Just edited post to show full error. Had to put some text below it because post was mainly code. 
When i change it to: ```if df['RSI'] < float('50'):``` the error I receive is ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```